# Twitter OAuth 2.0 PKCE: How to exchange authorization code for access token?

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0, authorization, access-token, pkce

I'm trying to follow the authentication flow for OAuth 2.0 PKCE as explained on the [Twitter documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/authorization-code), but I'm stuck in the last step.

I managed to get an authorization code from the callback URL, but I have no idea how to exchange it for an access token.

What URL am I supposed to query for this? How should the request look like?